# Check if variable exist more than once in array?

Tags: php, arrays, count, duplicates

I want to do an if/else statement in PHP that relies on an item in the array existing more than once or not. Can you use count in in_array? to do something like:

`if (count(in_array($itemno_array))) > 1 {
     EXECUTE CODE }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $item be the item whose frequency you are checking for in the array, $array be the array you are searching in.

SOLUTION 1:

```
$array_count = array_count_values($array); 
if (array_key_exists($item, $array_count) && ($array_count["$item"] > 1))
{
   /* Execute code */
}
```

array_count_values() returns an array using the values of the input array as keys and their frequency in input as values (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

SOLUTION 2:

```
if (count(array_keys($array, $item)) > 1) 
{
     /* Execute code */
}
```

Check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php - "If the optional search_value is specified, then only the keys for that value are returned"

Comment: You might like to cater for the instance where `$item` does not exist in `$array`.

Comment: I have edited and added another solution too. You may check it out.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

in_array only returns a bool, so you can't count it. array_keys however returns an array of all keys for an item in the array, so checking the length of that result will give you whether it exists more than once or not.

Comment: This will not work in all cases. What if the item that repeats is not the one he is looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what Gordon told. My bad. Realized he is talking about the search value parameter in array_keys function

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your question but maybe this is what you neeed:

```
if ( count($in_array) > count(array_unique($in_array)) ) 
{
 EXECUTE CODE
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. What if the item that repeats is not the one he is looking for?