# Skip row if more than one cell is empty with PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that generates an HTML table from a CSV file.

Right now if any cells are missing information, it skips the row. HOWEVER, I'd prefer if it skipped a row if more than one cell was missing. **So if a row has 2 empty cells, it should skip.**

I have marked it `//edit here` below but unsure how to acheive this.

```
<?php
$idsColumnsWanted = array(0,1,8,19);

echo "<table class='table table-bordered' id='example'>\n\n";

$f = fopen("users.csv", "r");
$first_line = false;

while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    // Restart column index
    $i = 0;
    $row ="";

    if($first_line == false) {
        $row = "<thead><tr>";
        $col = "th";
    } else {
        $row = "<tr>";
        $col= "td";
    }

    $is_empty = false;
    foreach ($line as $i => $cell) {
        // Skips all columns not in your list
        if (! in_array($i, $idsColumnsWanted)) continue;

        // edit here
        if ($cell !== '') {
            $row .= "<".$col.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "   </".$col.">";
        } else {
            $is_empty = true;
        }
        // Increase index
        $i++;
    }

    if($first_line == false)
        $row .= "</tr></thead>";
    else 
        $row .= "</tr>";

    $first_line = true;

    if ($is_empty) {
        continue;
    } else {
        echo $row;
    }
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Use a counter instead of a boolean variable, increase it when a cell is empty and check if it is bigger than 1 after the loop.

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882981/check-if-variable-exist-more-than-once-in-array. If more than one value (cell) in the line is empty, set $is_empty to true.

Comment: Cf. @jeroen, don't forget to reset the counter on each line start.
BTW, the thead/tr logic seems suspicious.

Comment: Many people suggest using a counter, if you ask me that is very unnecessary. PHP offers you functions to find the amount of occurrences in an Array, might as well use it instead of defining a rather (useless) counter

Comment: @PatrickAleman Rather than spraying downvotes everywhere, show the OP some code to demonstrate your idea

Comment: Unrelated note:  You don't need to do the `$i++;` bit at the end of the `foreach` loop - the loop construct sets the value of `$i` for you at the start of each iteration.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the link I posted gives a perfect example

Comment: @PatrickAleman has a good point.  Using `array_count_values` before processing each row not only leads to more concise code, but it also lets you avoid having to build up an HTML string (the `$row` variable) only to discard it later.  Although it would have been better if Patrick posted an answer to demonstrate this, rather than just a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this code

```
$is_empty = false;
$count = 0;
$countlimit = 2; // define empty cell limit here
foreach ($line as $i => $cell) {
    // Skips all columns not in your list
    if (!in_array($i, $idsColumnsWanted))
        continue;

    // edit here
    if($cell==""){
        $count++;
    }

    if ($count <= $countlimit) {
        $row .= "<" . $col . ">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "   </" . $col . ">";
    } else {
        $is_empty = true;
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have had to change `$countlimit = 1;` because it starts from `0` so it goes `0,1` thus 2. Thank you, @Rakesh :-D

Comment: No Its correct I think because it increment first and then check condition $count  <= $countlimit so its 2.

Comment: You might want to break out of the `foreach` after setting `$is_empty = true;`  Also, you don't really need the `$cell !== '' ||` bit, just `$count  <= $countlimit` on its own will do.

Comment: @daiscog : Yes you are right. I just need to edit my code. Thanks.

Comment: @daiscog : Please see now. and also I have to move // Increase index
$i++; upside.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've edited it, too:  The `$i++;` line is completely unnecessary (as per my comment under the question).  Also, you **do** need to have `$is_empty = true;` as well as the `break` because `$is_empty` is the variable tested after the `foreach` loop to decide whether to `echo $row`

Comment: @daiscog : yes you are right. Thank you for corrections.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cound how many cells are empty in a row. To do so init the counter for each line.

```
$empty_cells = 0; //Init with 0 for each line
foreach ($line as $i => $cell) {
    // Skips all columns not in your list
    if (! in_array($i, $idsColumnsWanted)) continue;

    // edit here
    if ($cell !== '') {
        $row .= "<".$col.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "   </".$col.">";
    } else {
        $empty_cells++; //count how many empty cells you have.
    }
    // Increase index
    $i++;
}
```

and after that check if there are more than two empty cells like this:

```
if ($empty_cells >= 2) {
    continue;
} else {
    echo $row;
}
```

Comment: After `$empty_cells++`, add in `if ($empty_cells == 2) break;` so the script doesn't have to keep looping through a row it isn't going to use.